# Is there a proper etiquette for asking an author for their (mathematical) software?

Tags: soft-question, math-software, advice

This may not be the correct place to ask such a question. I have read a mathematical paper on multiclass total variation clustering. I wish to use the algorithm in the contents to compare with another clustering result. My question is:

Is there a proper etiquette for asking the author(s) of the paper for their code? Is it rude to do so? Should I just try to figure it out on my own? Or is this something that is common?

One reason why I want to ask is because I am short on time and may not be able to figure it out by my deadline.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My $0.02, as someone who writes code (not mathematical, but just code) a lot: If someone who appears to know nothing about a subject straight up asks for my code, I decline.  If someone knows a lot about a subject and should be able to write it themselves given enough time, I say yes.  If someone is in the middle (they know some about the subject, but not enough to right the code themselves), I will say yes if they have shown effort.

Comment: "Dr. So-and-so, I am very interested in your paper titled `Title' appearing in the Journal of Interesting Papers. I think your algorithm is highly applicable to my data, but I'm having some trouble in the implementation. Do you happen to have some open-source code, or perhaps a buildable application, that I can use to benchmark my results?"

Comment: The above comment is, of course, really only applicable if it's true.

Comment: Great! Thank you guys. I've never asked before so I don't want to be rude. This is helpful.

Comment: For the future: [academia.SE] is where such questions are precisely on topic, and both mathematics and computer science are well represented in their user base.